# Remove "#" comment lines from the middle of a file

Tags: bash, shell

I want remove comment lines, beginning with "#", from the middle of a file, without removing header comment lines at the top of the file. How can I do this using shell scripts and standard Unix tools?

```
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE.
#Mon Jan 14 22:25:16 PST 2013
/test/v1=1.0
#PROPERTIES P1.   <------REMOVE THIS 
/test/p1=1.0
/test/p2=1.0
/test/p3=3.0
/test/p41=4.0
/test/v6=1.0
#. P2 PROPERTIES   <------REMOVE THIS
/test/p1=1.0
/test/p2=1.0
/test/p3=3.0
/test/p41=4.0
/test/v6=1.0
.................
.................
```

Output

```
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE.
#Mon Jan 14 22:25:16 PST 2013
/test/v1=1.0
/test/p1=1.0
/test/p2=1.0
/test/p3=3.0
/test/p41=4.0
/test/v6=1.0
/test/p1=1.0
/test/p2=1.0
/test/p3=3.0
/test/p41=4.0
/test/v6=1.0
.................
.................
```

Comment: You're asking how to modify a file that says "DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE." at the top?

Comment: I tried using sed the problem is that i'm not able to remove the comment in between the file, all are getting removed, I try to keep the first comment and rest all comment should be Ignored not able ti sucedd

Comment: I am gonna second the comment above.  You shouldn't modify that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR==2 || !/^#/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use awk:

```
head -n 2 file.txt > output.txt
grep -v "^#.*" file.txt >> output.txt
```

Comment: You can do that in one shot: `{ head -n 2 file.txt; grep -v '^#' file.txt; } > output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You want to echo the lines beginning with '#', but only at the beginning, using only bash? Start with a boolean `start=true`; then go line-by-line, set `start=false` when the line doesn’t start with `#`, and echo each line only if you are at the start or the line does not start with `#`.

Here’s the file `script`:

```
#!/bin/bash

start=true
while read line; do
    if $start; then
        if [ "${line:0:1}" != "#" ]; then
            start=false
        fi
    fi
    if $start || [ "${line:0:1}" != "#" ];  then
        echo "${line}"
    fi
done
```

Running it:

```
$ cat input
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE.
#Mon Jan 14 22:25:16 PST 2013
/test/v1=1.0
#PROPERTIES P1.
/test/p1=1.0
/test/p2=1.0
/test/p3=3.0
/test/p41=4.0
/test/v6=1.0
#. P2 PROPERTIES
/test/p1=1.0
/test/p2=1.0
/test/p3=3.0
/test/p41=4.0
/test/v6=1.0
$ ./script < input
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE.
#Mon Jan 14 22:25:16 PST 2013
/test/v1=1.0
/test/p1=1.0
/test/p2=1.0
/test/p3=3.0
/test/p41=4.0
/test/v6=1.0
/test/p1=1.0
/test/p2=1.0
/test/p3=3.0
/test/p41=4.0
/test/v6=1.0
```

Comment: Why did you choose to run the while loop in a subshell?

Comment: Good point—there is no good reason for that. I’ve fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed, you have

```
sed '3,${/^#/d}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
 sed '/^[^#]/,$!b;/^#/d' file
```

Comment: are you missing the closing slash on the opening regex ?